# I want to be able to build with nuxt

Tags: npm, nuxt.js, npx

An error occurred when performing npm run dev in the project after creating it with create-nuxt-app. I searched from the error, but could not find anything that matches the error content.

```
FATAL  URL is not defined                                                                              15:16:01

  at parseURL (node_modules/@nuxt/ufo/dist/index.js:22:15)
  at Object.normalizeURL (node_modules/@nuxt/ufo/dist/index.js:33:44)
  at Object.getNuxtConfig (node_modules/@nuxt/config/dist/config.js:4141:29)
  at new Nuxt (node_modules/@nuxt/core/dist/core.js:643:27)
  at NuxtCommand.getNuxt (node_modules/@nuxt/cli/dist/cli-index.js:2868:18)
  at <anonymous>
  at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:160:7)
  at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:703:11)
  at startup (bootstrap_node.js:193:16)
  at bootstrap_node.js:617:3


   ╭────────────────────────────────────────╮
   │                                        │
   │   ✖ Nuxt Fatal Error                   │
   │                                        │
   │   ReferenceError: URL is not defined   │
   │                                        │
   ╰────────────────────────────────────────╯

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! eshiritori-frontend@1.0.0 dev: `nuxt`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the eshiritori-frontend@1.0.0 dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/aaa/.npm/_logs/2020-12-08T06_16_01_831Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by removing the "^" from the nuxt version in package.json

before: "nuxt": "^2.11.0"

now: "nuxt": "2.11.0",